# How to close the default media player?

Tags: android, media-player

I have started the default media player using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+("/background.mp3"));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

But, when the file is played completely, I want to exit the media player.
How do we close the default media player which is started by 'intent'?
I have tried using the "`startActivityForResult()`"... But i don't know where to set the "`result`"

Comment: please let me know the implementation...

Comment: @Pallavi: Try reading the documentation for MediaPlayer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: @MisterSquonk, A sample implementation I was talking about. I have seen the SDK, but they are just functions of the Media player, no sample- how to invoke the media player etc!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your reply, I got the problem...
I had used:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+("/background.mp3"));
```

in my code. The `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` was the problem!!!
When i replaced it with "`/sdcard/background.mp3`" it works properly...

Answer (score 0):

you should have to use finish() after statring ur activity...

edit

use    mp.release();

private static final String TAG = "VideoPlayer";

```
private MediaPlayer mp;
private SurfaceView mPreview;

private SurfaceHolder holder;
private ImageButton mPlay;
private ImageButton mPause;
private ImageButton mReset;
private ImageButton mStop;
private String current;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Set up the play/pause/reset/stop buttons
    mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
    mPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.path);
    mPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    mPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    mReset = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    mStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);

    mPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            playVideo();
        }
    });
    mPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.pause();
            }
        }
    });
    mReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }
        }
    });
    mStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mp != null) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried that, but it finishes my previous activity not the media player's activity...

Comment: u should have to try like this..it is not complete code but just for understanding..

Comment: This is getting too complex... I did try to implement, but I am not able to hear the sound file...

Comment: The error is: `DEBUG/AudioSink(33): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12`. How to increase the buffer size? I cannot play smaller files...

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer Player2;
Player2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
Player2.start();

button click event{

Player2.stop();
}
```

In this example i have use Mediaplayer and i have get my resource from raw folder (res/raw.music.mp3).

i have use `stop();` method of media player to stop it

[For more here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)